# How to retrieve results that contain JSON from SQLite for use in a jinja template?

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a SQLite DB that I query like this:

```
 products = cursor.execute(
Select Item,EntryDate,json_group_array(json_object('color',P.option)) as colorarray
.....
).fetchall()
```

The results of products can look like this

```
[('dress', '2022-12-27 00:00:00', '[{"color":"blue"},{"color":"green"}]')]
```

In my jinja template I try to loop over the JSON, but my data is treated like a string and printed out 1 character at a time.

```
    {% for color in products[2] %}
    {{ color }}
    {% endfor %}
```

What is the proper way to get this done? I can change my SQLite query to not use json_group_array if there is a more idiomatic option. Also I would rather refer to my data by column names (ex products.colorarray) if possible.

I've tried this query with SQLite and also tried mocking the data.

Comment: (1) The first code sample isn't valid Python code. (2) For Sqlite and Python the JSON is just a string. Use module "json" to convert it to Python objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, `products[0][2]` is a string, in fact SQLite's [`json_object()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jobj) returns a serialized JSON, and beacuse strings are iterables you're noticing this:

> In my jinja template I try to loop over the JSON, but my data is treated like a string and printed out 1 character at a time.

deserialize `products[0][2]` with [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) .

> Also I would rather refer to my data by column names (ex products.colorarray) if possible.

Jinja can read a dictionary like this:

```
d = {
   "item": products[0][0],
   "timestamp": products[0][1],
   "colorarray": json.loads(products[0][2])
}
```

then get access by the `colorarray` key:

```
{% for color in d["colorarray"] %}
    {{ color["color"] }}
{% endfor %}
```